# How to set the key of the message?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am using Spring Cloud with Apache Kafka. The messages sent to a kafka topic usally contain a key as well. How can I set that key?

Let's say, I produce messages like this

```
@StreamListener(CashflowSink.T1_CASHFLOW_IN)
@SendTo(CashflowSink.T2_CASHFLOW_OUT)
public synchronized Cashflow receive1(String message) {
    System.out.println("******************");
    System.out.println("At Sink1");
    System.out.println("******************");
    System.out.println("Received message " + message);

    String arr[] = message.split(";");
    if (arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Cashflow")) {
        Cashflow cf = new Cashflow();
        cf.setContractId(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
        cf.setDate(arr[2]);
        cf.setAmount(Float.parseFloat(arr[3]));
        return cf;
    }

return null;
```

}

Later I want to join cashflows with other topics. For joins, I need a key. Let's say the key is the contractId of the cashflow. How can I set that key in the message?

**EDIT 1**

Trying to incorporate the code from Gary, I came up with:

```
    //@Bean //--> leads to: Parameter 0 of method runner in tki.bigdata.steams.CashflowService required a single bean, but 10 were found:
    @Qualifier("t2_cashflow_in")  // is this a correct way to get a handle to the channel?
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        ((AbstractMessageChannel) output).addInterceptor(0, new ChannelInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, ((Cashflow) message.getPayload()).getContractId())
                        .build();
            }

        });
        return args -> {            
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(CashflowSink.T2_CASHFLOW_IN)
    public synchronized void receive2(Cashflow cashflow, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) byte[] key) {
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("At Sink2");
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("Received cashflow " + cashflow);
        System.out.println(cashflow + ", key:" + new String(key));
    }
```

The @Bean annotation gave me an error, probably because there are multiple "channels". I followed a hint in the error message and used the @Channel annotation. Not sure, if this does what I want to achieve.

Executing that code, I am getting Errors like the following. So I assume the interception did not work?

```
2019-06-20 20:56:02,557 ERROR [Ljava.lang.String;@4195105b.container-0-C-1 o.s.k.l.LoggingErrorHandler:37 - Error while processing: ConsumerRecord(topic = tier2.cashflow, partition = 0, offset = 11, CreateTime = 1561056959426, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 63, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [RecordHeader(key = deliveryAttempt, value = [49]), RecordHeader(key = contentType, value = [34, 97, 112, 112, 108, 105, 99, 97, 116, 105, 111, 110, 47, 106, 115, 111, 110, 34]), RecordHeader(key = spring_json_header_types, value = [123, 34, 100, 101, 108, 105, 118, 101, 114, 121, 65, 116, 116, 101, 109, 112, 116, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 117, 116, 105, 108, 46, 99, 111, 110, 99, 117, 114, 114, 101, 110, 116, 46, 97, 116, 111, 109, 105, 99, 46, 65, 116, 111, 109, 105, 99, 73, 110, 116, 101, 103, 101, 114, 34, 44, 34, 99, 111, 110, 116, 101, 110, 116, 84, 121, 112, 101, 34, 58, 34, 106, 97, 118, 97, 46, 108, 97, 110, 103, 46, 83, 116, 114, 105, 110, 103, 34, 125])], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = [B@5884f4e2)
org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: Missing header 'kafka_receivedMessageKey' for method parameter type [class [B]
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.handleMissingValue(HeaderMethodArgumentResolver.java:105)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.support.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:117)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:148)
    at org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.cloud.stream.binding.StreamListenerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(StreamListenerMessageHandler.java:55)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:123)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:176)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:132)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:105)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:453)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:401)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MessageProducerSupport.sendMessage(MessageProducerSupport.java:205)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.sendMessageIfAny(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:369)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.access$400(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:74)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:431)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.inbound.KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationRecordMessageListener.onMessage(KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.lambda$onMessage$0(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:120)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.doExecute(RetryTemplate.java:287)
    at org.springframework.retry.support.RetryTemplate.execute(RetryTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(RetryingMessageListenerAdapter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1263)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeOnMessage(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1256)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1217)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doInvokeWithRecords(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1198)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeRecordListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.invokeListener(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:933)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:749)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:698)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

For the case that there is more useful information, I post the whole class

```
@EnableBinding(CashflowService.CashflowSink.class)
public class CashflowService {

    @StreamListener(CashflowSink.T1_CASHFLOW_IN)
    @SendTo(CashflowSink.T2_CASHFLOW_OUT)
    public synchronized Cashflow receive1(String message) {
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("At Sink1");
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("Received message " + message);

        String arr[] = message.split(";");
        if (arr[0].equalsIgnoreCase("Cashflow")) {
            Cashflow cf = new Cashflow();
            cf.setContractId(Integer.parseInt(arr[1]));
            cf.setDate(arr[2]);
            cf.setAmount(Float.parseFloat(arr[3]));

            return cf;
        }

        return null;

    }

    // @Bean //--> leads to: Parameter 0 of method runner in
    // tki.bigdata.steams.CashflowService required a single bean, but 10 were
    // found:
    @Qualifier("t2_cashflow_in") // is this a correct way to get a handle to the
                                    // channel?
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        ((AbstractMessageChannel) output).addInterceptor(0, new ChannelInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, ((Cashflow) message.getPayload()).getContractId()).build();
            }

        });
        return args -> {
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(CashflowSink.T2_CASHFLOW_IN)
    public synchronized void receive2(Cashflow cashflow, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) byte[] key) {
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("At Sink2");
        System.out.println("******************");
        System.out.println("Received cashflow " + cashflow);
        System.out.println(cashflow + ", key:" + new String(key));
    }

    public interface CashflowSink {
        String T1_CASHFLOW_IN = "t1_cashflow_in";
        String T2_CASHFLOW_IN = "t2_cashflow_in";
        String T1_CASHFLOW_OUT = "t1_cashflow_out";
        String T2_CASHFLOW_OUT = "t2_cashflow_out";

        @Input(T1_CASHFLOW_IN)
        SubscribableChannel t1_cashflow_in();

        @Input(T2_CASHFLOW_IN)
        SubscribableChannel t2_cashflow_in();

        @Output(T1_CASHFLOW_OUT)
        SubscribableChannel t1_cashflow_out();

        @Output(T2_CASHFLOW_OUT)
        SubscribableChannel t2_cashflow_out();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any Message in your code, only your custom classes, so I am not sure what do you expect from he framework. . . Consider providing more details

Comment: You have to promote it to a header using an interceptor. I'll post an example shortly.

Comment: Would be great to mentioned also that you deal with Apache Kafka and the `key` is exactly about its record keying support.

Comment: See my answer; we should probably add a `KafkaExpressionEvaluatingInterceptor` to the kafka binder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `messageKeyExpression` kafka extension producer property; the problem is, the expression is evaluated after the payload is converted (unless you are using `nativeEncoding`, in which case you can use that with `payload.contractId`).

If you are not using native encoding, you can add an interceptor (before the conversion interceptor) and promote the key to the `KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY` header.

Here is an example:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class So56689257Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56689257Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(MessageChannel output) {
        ((AbstractMessageChannel) output).addInterceptor(0, new ChannelInterceptor() {

            @Override
            public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
                return MessageBuilder.fromMessage(message)
                        .setHeader(KafkaHeaders.MESSAGE_KEY, ((Foo) message.getPayload()).getContractId().getBytes())
                        .build();
            }

        });
        return args -> {
            output.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(new Foo("someContractId")).build());
        };
    }

    @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
    public void listen(Foo foo, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) byte[] key) {
        System.out.println(foo + ", key:" + new String(key));
    }

    public static class Foo {

        private String contractId;

        public Foo() {
            super();
        }

        public Foo(String contractId) {
            this.contractId = contractId;
        }

        public String getContractId() {
            return this.contractId;
        }

        public void setContractId(String contractId) {
            this.contractId = contractId;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Foo [contractId=" + this.contractId + "]";
        }

    }

}
```

and

```
Foo [contractId=someContractId], key:someContractId
```

The RabbitMQ binder already has a built-in `RabbitExpressionEvaluatingInterceptor` (which evaluates expressions before payload conversion) but there is currently no equivalent in the Kafka binder, so you have to add your own interceptor.

Or, if you are using json, you can use `#jsonpath` in the expression to extract the key.

Comment: Awesome :-) Now I am confused about combining this intercepter with the method in my original post. Because I am creating the objects (Cashflow) there. Shouldn't the Intercepter been executed in the middle of that method somehow?

Comment: No; my example is a bit contrived. The interceptor needs to be added once during context initialization. In my case, I simply added the interceptor while building the `ApplicationRunner` `@Bean`; that code (before the `return`) is only invoked once. Whenever a message is sent to the output channel, e.g. your `return cf`, the interceptor is invoked to copy the key to the header. So, you need to get a handle to the channel in some configuration class. You can even do it the way I did, but with a "no-op" `ApplicatiomRunner` - `return args -> { };`.

Comment: could you have a look at *EDIT 1* in my question above?

Comment: Spring needs to know which `MessageChannel` to wire in. Since you have none called `output`, it doesn't know what you intend. The runner must be a `@Bean` and you either need to add a `@Qualifier("t1_cashflow_out )` on the `output` parameter (not on the method), or use `MessageChannel t1_cashflow_out`. Since you need to intercept both, add them both as parameters.

Comment: np; I opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/683) if you want to track it.